# How to use object properties to calculate a new variable in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a `DTO` as given below:

```
class Product
{
   public float cost{set;get;}
   public float sellprice{set;get}
}
```

And I have this `ViewModel`:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
   public Product products{set;get}
   public float profit{set;get}
}
```

The problem is that I need to calculate profit from `Product` properties but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a property with an expression-getter, like so:

```
public class MyViewModel{
    public MyViewModel( Product product )
    {
        this.Product = product ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(product));
    }
    public Product Product { get; }
    public Decimal Profit => this.Product.SellPrice - this.Product.Cost;
}
```

Other feedback:

- In C# and .NET:

  - Give types (`class`, `struct`, `interface`, etc) `PascalCase` names.
  - Give private fields, parameters and locals `camelCase` names.
  - Give public members (properties, methods) `PascalCase` names.
- Do not use `float` or `double` to represent currency.

  - [Why not use Double or Float to represent currency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency)
  - They are IEEE-754 approximate values, they cannot accurately represent certain (well, most) decimal values.
  - Use `System.Decimal` instead - or use `int` cents (premultiplied by 100x).
- You should aim for using immutable types with read-only properties.

  - Mutable state makes it harder to reason about data-flow in your application.